# Unity game not running in Fancybox iframe

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, fancybox, unity-game-engine

I am trying to embed my Unity game into Fancybox using an iframe. It runs fine when I open it in a separate webpage, but when embedded it does not load. This is the code I have at the top of the page:

http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=tJsjwVnH

And this is the code I'm using to try and bring up the game in fancybox:

http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=dsHKVt4n

I would really appreciate any help, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are binding this class to fancybox: `fancybox_swf`, but your anchor has this other class: `fancybox_unity`. Additionally, you don't have any `data-` attribute to pass the dimensions to fancybox.

I guess your anchor should look like

```
<a class="fancybox_swf fancybox.iframe" title="Shoot The Hoop" href="unity/WebPlayer.html" data-width="600" data-height="320">
 <img src="images/shootthehoop.png" alt="Shoot The Hoop" />
</a>
```

Set `data-width` and `data-height` values as your convenience, then you can use [your fancybox script](http://pastebin.com/embed_js.php?i=tJsjwVnH).

Notice that you have to set a HTML5 `DOCTYPE`.

Answer (score 0):

Oh oops, I accidentally cut out the wrong part of the code I pasted! I meant to edit out fancybox_swf but I cut out fancybox_unity. Anyway, turns out my host doesn't support unity3d files which is why it wasn't working, I hosted it somewhere else in the end but your code worked perfectly to link to the fancybox so thanks!